# -webkit-flex-shrink equivalent

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, shrink

Is there "-webkit-flex-shrink" equivalent property in old flexBox spec?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6weaseh/1/

```
.row {
    width: 300px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.row div:first-child {
    width: 100px;
}
.row div:last-child {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
}
.old {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
.new {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:horizontal;
}

.new div:first-child {
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}
.new div:last-child {
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
}
<div class="old row">
    <div>old</div>
    <div>laskjdf ;alksdj fl;aksjdf ;laskjdf ;laskjdf ;alskdjf ;alskdjf a;sldkfj a;sldkjf; asldjfk ;asdfasdfj ;alskdfj ;</div>
</div>
<div class="old row">
    <div>old</div>
    <div>short</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="new row">
    <div>new</div>
    <div>laskjdf ;alksdj fl;aksjdf ;laskjdf ;laskjdf ;alskdjf ;alskdjf a;sldkfj a;sldkjf; asldjfk ;asdfasdfj ;alskdfj ;</div>
</div>
<div class="new row">
    <div>new</div>
    <div>short</div>
</div>
```

The first row is using the old spec, and the second new. I need to make the first row like the second - using old spec.

Thanks